# Is there a clean way of users managing their own locations?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-smart-ip

A lot of my site is dynamically generated dependant on the user location.

To get an initial fix I am currently using the Smart_IP module which does this based on the user IP address - which works great as a starting point. I can access  `$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['longitude']` & `$_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['latitude']` as required - perfect!

But I need to allow my user to override this..

1. Using HTML5 geolocation. I want to only do this on user request, ie click 'locate me', rather than requesting their location uninvited.
2. Using one of a few pre-defined locations selectable by the user.
3. Using an inputed address by the user.

Is there any drupal module I can use for this, or how else could I achieve it?

-

Just to clarify, I am talking about anonymous users here - the general public visiting my site. I just want them to be able to refine their 'location' by overriding the defaults I give them using smart_ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suggest to use [Geolocation field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) and all it's submodules or [Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield). Last one provides more input methods.
2. Use the [Address field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module to allow the user create multiple addresses into a node (or even into his profile), [Geocoder](https://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module to get the lon/lat from these addresses and then a [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to display them in a list.
3. Same as 2 but without views.

If you want to allow user select one of the 3 methods you can use an other - helper - field (eg **a select list** with the 3 options).

Finally you should add an **extra field to store the lat/lon** pair final values maybe with [Computed field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module or 2 simple textfields that will get the selected values through javascript.

Comment: If you are talking about anonymous users you should use views module to create the results display and then some modules like https://drupal.org/project/openlayers_proximity or https://drupal.org/project/geolocation_proximity to allow users filter the results. But in any case the functionality you describe seems to need a custom module and some javascript.